# Broken Woocommerce Shop Display - wont show products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

My shop page currently shows categories and previously I had set this to "Product Categories" in the admin area under woocommerce >> Product catalog.

Now things have changed and I want products to display instead of categories, however, every time I try to change this it defaults back to "Product Categories". (image below)

[Screenshot - Shop Catalog Display Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz0xx.png)

I have:

- Updated everything to the latest version
- Checked for duplicate pages
- Removed all custom code
- Switched back to default theme
- Disabled all products apart from woocommerce

The problem still persists, does anyone have a code snippet I can use to force products to show?

I can only think there is an issue with the database not being able to save or something.

Any ideas will help

Comment: do you see any browser console error when saving the value? hit `CLTR+SHIFT+I` and then hit the save button & look into console tab if there's any red error

Comment: @SajjadHossainSagor No error as it does save (says "published") then I refresh and it defaults back to categories